# very simple program to draw a filled rectangle .. why it does not work ?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I am new with using graphics and I am trying to draw a filled rectangle when the form opens.. but nothing is working and do not know the reason

here is my code :

```
private void Result_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new       System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
    System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
    formGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 200,300));
    myBrush.Dispose();
    formGraphics.Dispose();
}
```

where Result is my form that is supposed I draw the rectangle on when it is loaded

but when I load the form nothing happens at all

where the problem ?

thanks in advance

Comment: It's because OnPaint refreshes your drawing. Put your code in Paint event.

Comment: @general-doomer Turn this into an answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add handler to `Paint` event in form's constructor:

```
/// <summary>
/// form constructor
/// </summary>
public frmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Paint += frmMain_Paint;
}
```

And create method frmMain_Paint:

```
void frmMain_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Green))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 300));
    }
}
```

**Tips**

1. Use e.Graphics to draw (not `this.CreateGraphics()`)
2. Use `using` keyword as in example above.

Comment: There is no need for myBrush.Dispose() since it is instantiated in using statement.

Comment: You right, I just copied author's code. `Dispose` is not needed